# Expected value for random walk

Tags: probability, self-learning

A point starts at the origin and can randomly go up, down, left, right (equally likely).

The question asks to write the expression of the point's position in terms of $x_1$ -units up, $x_2$ -units down, $x_3$ -units left, $x_4$ -units down, and its expected value $E(D^2)$ after $n$ moves.

After n moves I found the expression to be:

$$D^2=(x_4-x_3)^2+(x_1-x_2)^2$$

Now I need to find the expected value for $D^2$ and I am not sure how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $x_1 = \sum_{i=1}^n 1_{\text{up on move $i$}}$ and similarly for $x_2,x_3,x_4$. Expand the squares and take expected values.

You get terms like $E[x_1^2]$ and $E[x_1x_2]$.

We have
$$
x_1^2 = \sum_{i\neq j }^n 1_{\text{up on $i$, up on $j$}} + \sum_{i=1}^n 1_{\text{up on $i$}}
$$
so
$$
E[x_1^2] = \sum_{i\neq j}^nP({\text{up on $i$, up on $j$}}) + \sum_{i=1}^n P({\text{up on $i$}})
= (n^2-n)\frac1{16} + n \frac14
$$
Use linearity of expectation.
Note that going up on $i$ and up on $j$ are independent when $i\neq j$.
Similarly, for $x_1x_2$ we have
$$
x_1x_2 = \sum_{i\neq j} 1_{\text{up on $i$, down on $j$}} 
$$
so
$$
E[x_1x_2] = (n^2-n)\frac1{16}
$$
where there are no diagonal terms since  you can't go up and down on $i$. Again going up on $i$ and down on $j$ are independent events for $i\neq j$.

You should have everything you need to solve the problem now.

Comment: After expanding the squares I get:$$E(x_1^2)+E(x_2^2)+E(x_3^2)+E(x_4^2)-2E(x_1x_2)-2E(x_3x_4)$$ and when I sub in the sums I am not sure how to cancel them out. The answer should come to E(D^2)=n.

Comment: I showed you how to handle every term. Use that $E\sum (..) = \sum E[..]$.

Comment: And $E[1_{..}] = P(..)$